# C# and excel cubefield item list

Tags: c#, excel, vba, olap, excel-interop

I'm trying to automate testing of excel add-in that allows you to create some analysis entities based on  pivot table definition. 
I'm able to create random pivot table using cubefield objects(I'm adding random fields to rows,columns, and measures) but I need also to add some filtering and here I'm stuck. 
Is there any way to get cubefield item list ? For example when I have date field in filter 
list of all days and then I want to select some random days for filtering.

This is my code maybe it's not elegant but it works for my purpose. 
I'm basically grabbing cubefields check if it's measure or dimension and then I'm setting 
it's orientation.

```
public  void PivotTableFieldList()
{

        _currentPivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable) _worksheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1");
        _currentPivotTable.ManualUpdate = true;

        List<Excel.CubeField> measureList = new List<Excel.CubeField>();
        List<Excel.CubeField> dimensionList = new List<Excel.CubeField>();

        foreach (Excel.CubeField field in _currentPivotTable.CubeFields)
        {
            if (field.CubeFieldType == Excel.XlCubeFieldType.xlMeasure && field.ShowInFieldList)
            {
               measureList.Add(field);
            }
        }

        foreach (Excel.CubeField field in _currentPivotTable.CubeFields)
        {
            if (field.CubeFieldType != Excel.XlCubeFieldType.xlMeasure && field.ShowInFieldList)
            {
                dimensionList.Add(field);
           }
        }

        Random dimRan=new Random();
        dimRan.Next(0, dimensionList.Count);
        Random mesRan = new Random();
        mesRan.Next(0, measureList.Count);
        dimensionList.ToArray();
        measureList.ToArray();

        Excel.CubeField[] measureRandomList= new Excel.CubeField[3];
        Excel.CubeField[] dimensionRandomList = new Excel.CubeField[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            measureRandomList[i] = measureList[mesRan.Next(1, measureList.Count)];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            dimensionRandomList[i] = dimensionList[dimRan.Next(i, dimensionList.Count)];
         }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var field = measureRandomList[i];
            var name = measureRandomList[i].Name;
            field.Orientation= Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
        }

        dimensionRandomList[0].Orientation= Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
        dimensionRandomList[1].Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
        dimensionRandomList[2].Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
        dimensionRandomList[2].EnableMultiplePageItems=true;


        //How can I get cubefield items list ? 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your fields like this:

```
yourPivotField.CurrentPageName = string.Format("[{0}].[{1}].&[{2}]", SheetName, FieldName, FieldValue);
```

This sets the filter of your pivot table

[image: set Excel Filter]

Not sure if it it this you were searching for.

Comment: Hello Fabian, thanks for your answer, problem is that I don't know what members are inside pivotField or rather cubefield because I'm using olap data source. So for instance one time I will have years in filter and next time I will have some machines names.  So what I was trying to do was to grab some members randomly(e.g like on your screenshot numbers 38,42) and pass it to filter. But I can't find way to get this values.